# Question about "What does XYZ Cloud Technologies, Inc. offer that Big Tech clouds don't?"

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my [Software Engineering Stack Exchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/420441/what-does-american-virtual-cloud-technologies-inc-offer-that-big-tech-clouds-d)

How can I make this on topic, please?

The close reason is

> Questions asking us to find or recommend tools, libraries, programming languages, resources (including books, blogs, tutorials, and examples), or projects to undertake are off-topic here as they attract opinionated answers that won't have lasting value to others.

But I'm not asking anyone to find or recommend anything. I already identified the cloud computing platforms.

### My question

I am not affiliated with the company mentioned in the question. Don't hesitate to discuss other similar teeny cloud computing platforms.

I just don't understand why they still exist, and haven't either gone bankrupt, or been acquired by one of Big Tech's cloud computing gorillas like [Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud, IBM Cloud, Microsoft Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud-computing_comparison#PaaS_(Platform_as_a_service)).  How does the mentioned company distinguish itself from Big Tech?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make this on topic, please?

I fear, this kind of question can't be made on topic.

This site is about software engineering, which covers the list of topics listed on our ["on topic" page in the help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The economics of certain tech firms, their history or development at the market is clearly not on that list.

Note also the SE sites are no discussion sites. Questions why certain things did *not* happen in the past are purely speculative, so they have no right answer and would probably require a discussion. But as you can see on any [Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) page, questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion are not suitable for the stackexchange format. Hence I think there is no stackexchange site at all where this kind of question would fit in.

Finally, let me say what you wrote looks suspiciously like some kind of advertisement for a specific company. I assume this was not intentional, but I took the freedom to remove all references to the specific company from your meta question, since it does not matter here which company was asked about.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. "Questions why certain things did not happen in the past are purely speculative, so they have no right answer and would probably require a discussion. " what about world building ?

Comment: @Ineverattendeduniversity: ok, you are right, that description does not fit to [world building SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think they would accept the question in stake as well, it does not fit to their [on topic list](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i know. i'm just clarifying that speculations and discussions are on topic on some SE's.